# PHP run script then redirect once complete

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups, mysql-backup

in PHP how can I redirect my page once scrpit has run with a successful case 0 but stay on current page for anything else?

```
exec( $command, $output = array(), $worked );

switch( $worked ) {

    case 0:  
        echo "Database <b>". $database. "</b> successfully exported to <b>". $filename. '</b>';
      // add redirect here
        break;

    case 1:
        echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>'. $database .'</b> to <b>'. $filename .'</b>';
        break;

    case 2:

        echo 'There was an error during import.'
            . 'Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:'
            . '<br/><br/><table>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>'. $database .'</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>'. $user .'</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>'. $host .'</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>'. $filename .'</b></td>'
            . '</tr></table>'
        ;
        break;
}
```

Comment: write this line in case 0    redirect('another_page', 'refresh');

Comment: You cannot echo before a redirect because you'll get an error.

Comment: doing it as redirect would it be redirect("page.php", "refresh); or full url?

Comment: redirect is code igniter  function if you are working in core php so you can need to use   header("Location : your full urll");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind removing your "echo" before the redirect you can redirect with header

```
 header("Location: http://you-url");
```

If not you can use javascript

```
<script> window.location = "http://your-url"; </script>
```

And you could add something to delay the redirect or put your "successfully exported" message on an alert before the redirect, otherwise the user might not see the message if the redirect works too fast.